# how to create row and columns in bootstrap 4 like the picture?

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid

i have to create a layout like below picture in bootstrap 4.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqJEJ.jpg

Comment: Does the layout order matter? I mean do you want to show Post1 in right of side the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made one. check this code:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6 d-flex align-items-md-stretch">
            <div class="jumbotron ">
               Post 5 Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                    <div class="jumbotron">
                     post 1   Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                    <div class="jumbotron">
                    post 2    Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                    <div class="jumbotron">
                    post3    Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                    <div class="jumbotron">
                    post 4    Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks. now i have to dynamically this codes for wordpress. i need wordpress loop and query for display last 5 post. can you help me?

Comment: I know PHP and use it in some frameworks like Laravel but I don't use CSM. I suggest asking your question with code. 
if you don't know anything about PHP, need to learn it and then if you can't earn your target you can ask here about your problem by showing code.